# Isomorphisms of $L$-algebras and $L\supset K$-algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products, noncommutative-algebra

I have a minor technical problem with algebra isomorphisms. Suppose $L/K$ is a field extension and $A,A'$ are $L$-algebras such that for some $K$-algebras $X,X'$ holds $A\otimes_KX\cong A'\otimes_KX'$ (as $K$-algebras). If $C$ is another $L$-algebra, do we then know that
$$C\otimes_L(A\otimes_KX)\cong C\otimes_L(A\otimes_KX')$$
as $L$-algebras, wherein the $K$-algebras $A\otimes_KX$ and $A'\otimes_KL'$ are considered as $L$-allgebras wrt the first component (i.e. $\alpha(x\otimes y)$ is defined as $\alpha x\otimes y$ for $\alpha\in L$)? The problem arose in the context of a specific proof and I could give more details about the algebras in question, but I think this should either hold or not in full generality.

Edit: I shall specify the algebras in question. The setting is that of Brauer equivalence of algebras (two simple artinian algebras are Brauer equivalent if they're isomorphic to a matrix algebra over the same division algebra): $A$ is a simple central artinian $K$-algebra, $B\subset A$ a simple finite-dimensional subalgebra, $C$ its centraliser. Since $B$ is simple, its centre $L$ is a field, so $B$ and $C$ are $L$-algebras. By a previous step in the proof we know $B^\circ\otimes A$ and $C$ are Brauer equivalent simple artinian algebras (where the plain $\otimes$ denotes $\otimes_K$), which implies there are $m,n\in\Bbb N$ such that
$$C\otimes M_m(K)\cong (B^\circ\otimes A)\otimes M_n(K)$$
as $K$-algebras. Now at this point in the proof the following manipulation takes place
$$(B\otimes_LC)\otimes M_m(K)\cong B\otimes_L(C\otimes M_m(K))\color{red}{\cong}B\otimes_L((B^\circ\otimes A)\otimes M_n(K)),$$
where the isomorphisms are that of $L$-algebras. Why does the highlighted isomorphism hold?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez You're right... If I were to make an addendum to the question specifying what the algebras are, could you take a look?